# How to automate a Silverlight based web application using selenium?

Tags: silverlight, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to automate a web application using selenium, however that application is developed using Silverlight. Hence, i am not able to inspect the elements in the web page. Could anyone please suggest on how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box, selenium won't natively support testing a Silverlight-based web app.  There is https://code.google.com/archive/p/silverlight-selenium/, but it doesn't look like that project is currently being maintained.  Beyond that, Silverlight itself is not longer under development, and it won't run on recent versions of Chrome or Edge (or Android or iOS).